# Why did switching to from an infinite loop to TimerTask cause this drop in CPU usage?

Tags: java, multithreading, cpu, timertask

I wrote a daemon which was structured like this:

```
while( true ) {
  // do some stuff
  Thread.sleep( 1000 );
}
```

I noticed it was using a very large amount of CPU - up to 100%. I have had a similar daemon on my production servers for some months with the same CPU problem.

Yesterday I refactored the code to use [TimerTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html). Immediately I noticed that CPU usage had decreased on my dev box. So I decided to deploy to production and double-check using Munin. Here are the graphs:

[image: Load average]

[image: CPU usage]

A couple of points:

- There is absolutely nothing else running on the production server except the JVM.
- There are no other application threads running
- It was definitely executing the old-style code at the correct periodic intervals - I always write to the log each time the thread executes.

So: why is Thread.sleep so inefficient compared to TimerTask?

Comment: Can you produce a short but complete program demonstrating the same effect? How many threads do you have doing this?

Comment: Good idea. I will try to get something together later.

Comment: .sleep() keeps synchronized objects locked. So, maybe the answer is TimerTask uses .wait() instead? I'm not sure, but had to try

Comment: @biovamp this was the path I was going down too, but don't know Java well enough to be sure. And now I need to double-check my own application logic before I go any further..

Comment: TimerTask does in fact use `wait()`. see the `mainLoop` for `queue.wait(executionTime - currentTime)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Three possibilities I can think of:

- You have a *huge* number of threads doing this, and they're context switching all the time. Using a timer will mean there's only *one* thread instead. On the other hand, that means you will only get one task executing at a time.
- You have a `continue;` statement somewhere in your loop before the sleep, so even if the main body of work of the loop isn't executing very frequently, *something* is. It's hard to say without seeing some more concrete code though.
- You have a broken JVM/OS combination. This seems pretty unlikely, admittedly.

A simple loop *just* executing `Thread.sleep(1000)` repeatedly should be very cheap - and that should be easy for you to verify, too.

Comment: I've always wonder about the possibility of degenerate cases of Interrupted Exceptions (that are also swallowed) in cases like these ... no idea if it's even possible, or just some unfounded paranoia I've harbored for years.

Comment: @pst: Again that goes back to how often the start of the thread is *actually* being executed - and whether `InterruptedException` *is* being swallowed, of course. That's where it'll be handy when the OP has a repro case.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Two things. Firstly, I checked out my old version and added some more logging to double-check that there was no continue statement or other strangeness going on. Definitely Thread.sleep()'ing correctly, CPU usage still as high as before. I also wrote a 6 line Java class isolated from my main application with a while(true) loop as above, and it runs fine with next-to-no CPU usage. So it's pointing to a problem somewhere else in my JVM/code. There's no locking/synchronization going on in my while() loop at least. Is there anything else that could affect a thread's performance?

Comment: @robw: Only other threads... could it be that something else is starting a thread without you being aware? I would take a copy of your code, and then start hacking at it to gradually remove more and more of it until the problem goes away. For example, if you keep the rest of the code that happens *before* your loop, but then change your loop into *just* the sleep, does that still show the problem?

Comment: Ok - so in the while(true) version, I removed everything else from the while() loop except Thread.sleep(1000) and a System.out.println(). Still the same ultra-high CPU usage. Switch it to a TimerTask and it drops to almost zero. Strange. I'm not desperate to get to the bottom of this as for my purposes using the TimerTask works just fine, but it's an interesting one for sure. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Compare the speed of your processor, a thread and a timertask. The timertask is a slower thread (much slower).